# Modify ACL permissions of file on windows shared(SMB) location

Tags: java, acl, samba, jcifs

Is there any java api to manipulate ACL file/directory permissions on windows shared location ?

I have tried with samba jcifs library but we can only read the Access Control Entries but can not modify them.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I´m having the exact same issue.

Comment: Yes. Please go through the http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/setcifsacl.8.html. It might helps you.